# Register services with basic authentication fails

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

We try to publish a service, this fails into a 401 error. The endpoint and WSDL are protected with basic authentication. It looks like that the authentication fails, we have set the option "Endpoint Security Scheme" and entered valid credentials.

Note: The WSDL endpoint is working the a normal browser.
Note: We are using WSO2 AM 1.6.0

Here is the stack dump.

```
2014-01-22 15:10:26,929 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-33] ERROR APIMWSDLReader  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
2014-01-22 15:10:26,929 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-33] ERROR APIUtil Failed to reset the WSDL : http://myhost.nl:8080/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException:  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:767)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:1111)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:368)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:45)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_addAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:475)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:113)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2259)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:84)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:158)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2238)
        ... 69 more
2014-01-22 15:10:26,942 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-33] ERROR UserAwareAPIProvider Error while performing registry transaction operation
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to reset the WSDL : http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:787)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:1111)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:368)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:45)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_addAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:475)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:113)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException:  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:767)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2259)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:84)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:158)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2238)
        ... 69 more
2014-01-22 15:10:26,946 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-33] ERROR APIProviderHostObject Error while adding the API- leesaanvraag-1.0
org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error in adding API :leesaanvraag
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:381)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.UserAwareAPIProvider.addAPI(UserAwareAPIProvider.java:45)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.hostobjects.APIProviderHostObject.jsFunction_addAPI(APIProviderHostObject.java:475)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.FunctionObject.call(FunctionObject.java:386)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag:6)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c3.call(/publisher/modules/api/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.applyOrCall(ScriptRuntime.java:2430)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.BaseFunction.execIdCall(BaseFunction.java:269)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.IdFunctionObject.call(IdFunctionObject.java:97)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call2(OptRuntime.java:42)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag:5)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.modules.api.c0.call(/publisher/modules/api/module.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_anonymous_1(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:113)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call0(OptRuntime.java:23)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0._c_script_0(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag:4)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.call(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.rhino.publisher.site.blocks.item_add.ajax.c0.exec(/publisher/site/blocks/item-add/ajax/add.jag)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.execScript(RhinoEngine.java:570)
        at org.jaggeryjs.scriptengine.engine.RhinoEngine.exec(RhinoEngine.java:273)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.manager.WebAppManager.execute(WebAppManager.java:432)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryServlet.doPost(JaggeryServlet.java:29)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:755)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:749)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:487)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:379)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339)
        at org.jaggeryjs.jaggery.core.JaggeryFilter.doFilter(JaggeryFilter.java:21)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:178)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:56)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:141)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:156)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
        at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while performing registry transaction operation
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.AbstractAPIManager.handleException(AbstractAPIManager.java:666)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:1147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.addAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:368)
        ... 63 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Failed to reset the WSDL : http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:787)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.APIProviderImpl.createAPI(APIProviderImpl.java:1111)
        ... 64 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException:  Error occurs when change the addres URL of the WSDL
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:103)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIUtil.createWSDL(APIUtil.java:767)
        ... 65 more
Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=OTHER_ERROR: Unable to resolve imported document at 'http://myhost.nl:8080/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl'.: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2259)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2207)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readWSDLFile(APIMWSDLReader.java:128)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.utils.APIMWSDLReader.readAndCleanWsdl(APIMWSDLReader.java:84)
        ... 66 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: http://myhost.nl:8080/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1626)
        at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1037)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.util.StringUtils.getContentAsInputStream(StringUtils.java:158)
        at com.ibm.wsdl.xml.WSDLReaderImpl.readWSDL(WSDLReaderImpl.java:2238)
        ... 69 more
2014-01-22 15:10:26,951 [-] [http-nio-9443-exec-33] ERROR add:jag org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.api.APIManagementException: Error while adding the API- leesaanvraag-1.0
```

Could this be related to ISSUE:

https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1841

Comment: Your  hosted WSDL is protected with basicauth? If so, in the 1.6.0 version , we are not passing auth parameters for a protected WSDL..But we support endpoint security..not the secured WSDL..

Comment: The endpoint, http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG is protected with basic auth. So the WSDL as well http://myhost.nl/orawsv/SNL_OWNER/WSO_AANVRAGEN/LEES_AANVRAAG?wsdl It is impossible to register/publish a (web-)service that is protected. It looks to me as a bug. So I should only register the end-point, and the consumer in the store is not able read the WSDL....

Comment: Can someone from WSO2 confirm that it is not possible to register a webservice that is protected with basic authentication?

Comment: you can provide service endpoint URL which is protected with basic Auth. That support is available. If you click, secured option, it will ask username/password. Please provide your credentials there. But when you provide WSDL url, we are not checking basic auth headers at the moment..that support is not available at the moment

Comment: IMHO: I have set the endpoint URL with basic Auth. When I submit a message to the service I get a gateway time out. If I call the endpoint directly, with credential, it works. What can be wrong?

Comment: Can you create a JIRA with error logs and other details? we will be able to check..

Comment: Further investigantion shows the issue is NOT related to basic authentication for invoking the service.

I hope that WSO2 will improve the that they can also consume WSDL which are protected by B.A.

Comment: We have created a jira to track this, https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-1986 y